# Troubleshoot firewall config, find what is blocking ports

Tags: iptables, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ufw

I'm facing a problem with some firewall configuration.

I've got a VM on Google cloud (based on a bitnami image), and I can't connect to it through port 80.
I've set up some firewall rule with the standard Firewall tool by google.
Also I've setted up the same rule with UFW, but the port is still closed.

I've checked the Google firewall logs, and it's all fine, port 80 is not being blocked (i can seed the "ACCEPTED" status), so i did not think that is the Google firewall that close the port.
I can't find UFW log nowhere on my VM, also doing `grep -r "ufw" /` I can find only the installation log entry.
The only accessible port that I can find is 22.

What am I doing wrong, are there any other kind of firewalls that I don't know about?

And more generally, how can i understand where the request is blocked, is there any tool that can tell me who is closing the port?

[Google cloud firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7V5b.png)

[UFW firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Dv5.png)

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was vsftpd that is blockig all port exept 22, I've uninstalled it and everything is working fine now.